# Unable to store values in a python Dataframe column(derived) from another column(parent)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I've got a tricky problem here and am hoping someone can guide me on what needs to be done. I have a column in python dataframe which captures date and time separated by a " - " e.g. `2019-04-05 - 05:30`

When I'm trying to capture just the date part of the string, leaving out the time part on a single cell, it seems to be working fine:

```
x="2019-04-05 - 05:30"
y=[x][:10]
y
2019-04-05
```

But when I try to do the same operation to an entire column using a loop, it doesn't update anything and leaves the derived column as (blank).

```
i=0
for i in range(len(df1["DEPDATE &TIME"])):
    b = df1["DEPDATE &TIME"][i].find(" - ")
    df1["Departure"][i]=df1["DEPDATE &TIME"][i][:b]
df1["Departure"][i]
''
```

I've tried a couple other things using `.iloc` as well but all in vain. *Am I missing a trick here?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a for-loop, you can use the `str` extensions to do this.

```py
df1["Departure"] = df1["DEPDATE &TIME"].str.split(' - ').str.get(0)
```

Comment: Thanks James, it worked fine. Any reason why mine didn't work for a loop?

Comment: I suspect your for loop was setting the value on a copy of the series column, so it was not saving it back to the data frame

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import datetime
df1['Departure']= df1['DEPDATE &TIME'].dt.date
```

It applies in cases where your column DEPDATE &TIME is in datetime64